# Finding the cell of a button object in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, button

I used the macro recorder to assign some action to a button in excel (not an active-X button). All I want is for a row to be copied, the copy inserted onto a new row. This works fine, but I need ideally, I set up the code to simply copy the row directly above the button. The button moves with the cell it is in so it seem like I should be able to reference the row the button is on, copy the row above and insert a copy of the row above the copied row. How can I reference the current cell the button is in?

I am basically looking to insert a new row so the user can enter a new "step". It's a sort of project management document template. The row being copied will be a hidden row and the new row will be inserted above the hidden row for the user to enter more info.

The code below is what the macro record comes up with. This works, but the row I need to copy will not always be row 24.

```
Sub Button8_Click()
'
' Button8_Click Macro
'

    Rows("24:24").Select  'row above button
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Rows("25:25").Select 
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

The code above adds a copy of the row as expected. What I am looking for is to basically copy a row so the user can add another step in the excel doc I am making. Depending on how many steps they have added, I will not necessarily want to reference the rows that are in this code.

Comment: If that row is the bottom of your document, could you just find the last row with data in it and assume that's the row above your button?

Comment: Its not. It will pretty much always be in the middle of the worksheet, which is why I would like to find a way to know what row the button is on.  There are also several such buttons in the column. I would just want the row above copied and inserted into a new row.

Answer (score 2):

If your data was in column A:

```
Sub Button8_Click()

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Rows(lastrow & ":" & lastrow).Copy
Rows(lastrow & ":" & lastrow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(lastrow & ":" & lastrow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code that worked for me. TopLeftCell range will get the cell reference I was looking for.

```
Sub rowselect()

Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
Dim Row2 As Integer
Dim Row As Integer


Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
With b.TopLeftCell
Row = .Row - 1
Row2 = Cells(Row, "e")
End With

Rows(Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Cells(Row + 1, "e") = Row2 + 1
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False



End Sub
```